# Flutter Getx: google signin and map data to firebase automatically logs me back in as same user?

Tags: flutter, firebase, cart, flutter-getx

I am trying to login with google and have the data mapped to a firebase user. I'm using getX. So far this works HOWEVER it automatically logs me back in as the same user if I logout and then try to log back in again. I'll send the code for my login page and the page where the logout button is if needed, but I suspect this may have to do with my AuthController which I've included here

```
class AuthController extends GetxController {
  static AuthController instance = Get.find();
  GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  Rxn<User> firebaseUser = Rxn<User>();
  Rxn<UserModel> firestoreUser = Rxn<UserModel>();
  final RxBool admin = false.obs;
  String usersCollection = "users";

  @override
  void onReady() async {
    //run every time auth state changes
    ever(firebaseUser, handleAuthChanged);
    firebaseUser.bindStream(user);
    super.onReady();
  }

  handleAuthChanged(firebaseUser) async {
    //get user data from firestore
    if (firebaseUser?.uid != null) {
      firestoreUser.bindStream(streamFirestoreUser());
      print("You are logged in as ${firebaseUser.email}");
      await isAdmin();
    }
    //this is for new users
    if (firebaseUser == null) {
      print('Send to signin');
      Get.offAll(LoginPage());
    } else {
      Get.offAll(AppSetup());
    }
  }

  // Firebase user one-time fetch
  Future<User> get getUser async => auth.currentUser!;

  // Firebase user a realtime stream
  Stream<User?> get user => auth.authStateChanges();

  //Streams the firestore user from the firestore collection
  Stream<UserModel> streamFirestoreUser() {
    print('streamFirestoreUser()');

    return firebaseFirestore
        .doc('/users/${firebaseUser.value!.uid}')
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => UserModel.fromSnapshot(snapshot));
  }

  //get the firestore user from the firestore collection
  Future<UserModel> getFirestoreUser() {
    return firebaseFirestore
        .doc('/users/${firebaseUser.value!.uid}')
        .get()
        .then((documentSnapshot) => UserModel.fromSnapshot(documentSnapshot));
  }

  //Method to handle user sign in using email and password

  // User registration using email and password
  googleLogin(BuildContext context) async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    if (googleUser != null) {
      final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
      if (googleAuth.accessToken != null && googleAuth.idToken != null) {
        try {
          await auth
              .signInWithCredential(
            GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
                idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
                accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken),
          )
              .then((firebaseUser) async {
            print('uid: ' + firebaseUser.user!.uid.toString());
            print('email: ' + firebaseUser.user!.email.toString());

            //create the new user object from the login modelled data
            UserModel _newUser = UserModel(
              id: firebaseUser.user!.uid,
              email: firebaseUser.user!.email!,
              name: firebaseUser.user!.email!,
              photoURL: firebaseUser.user!.photoURL,
              cart: [],
            );
            //create the user in firestore here with the _addUserToFirestore function
            _updateUserFirestore(_newUser, firebaseUser.user!);
          });
        } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
          Get.snackbar('auth.signUpErrorTitle'.tr, error.message!,
              snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
              duration: Duration(seconds: 10),
              backgroundColor: Get.theme.snackBarTheme.backgroundColor,
              colorText: Get.theme.snackBarTheme.actionTextColor);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  void _updateUserFirestore(UserModel user, User _firebaseUser) {
    firebaseFirestore.doc('/users/${_firebaseUser.uid}').update(user.toJson());
    update();
  }

  updateUserData(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    logger.i("UPDATED");
    firebaseFirestore
        .collection(usersCollection)
        .doc(firebaseUser.value!.uid)
        .update(data);
  }

  //check if user is an admin user
  isAdmin() async {
    await getUser.then((user) async {
      DocumentSnapshot adminRef =
          await firebaseFirestore.collection('admin').doc(user.uid).get();
      if (adminRef.exists) {
        admin.value = true;
      } else {
        admin.value = false;
      }
      update();
    });
  }

  // This is the proper sign out method!
  Future<void> signOut() {
    return auth.signOut();
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't see where you signed out of google auth. I think you have to signOut. Add this `if (!kIsWeb) await googleSignIn.signOut();` before `return auth.signOut();`

Comment: That does not work... ```if (!kIsWeb) await googleSignIn.signOut();```, where are you getting ```(!kIsWeb) ```??

Comment: from here: `import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';` We use it to check if its web. For now, you can just do `await googleSignIn.signOut();` and check if it works.

Comment: thank you. I am also having other issues with this

Answer (score 2):

Simply add this line of code into your logout function

```
> await googleSignIn.signOut()
```